Error 404 HTTP, Repository with apt-mirror
My English is not very good, but I'm going to explain it as best as possible.
First of all the repository is a Ubuntu server 22 to update a ubuntu 18 to a Ubuntu 22 or 20 the version doesn't matter to me (but i prefer the 22), the server and the client have a ip static.
and i follow some instruccions of this repository of github, here is the link of the repository:
https://github.com/Stifler6996/apt-mirror/blob/master/apt-mirror
I only do the part of apt-mirror and README. and i was thinking to do the part of mirror.list but i didn't do it because the version is precise, is necessary that i need to do with this version? . finally I do the apt-mirror: "sudo apt-mirror"
Then I install Apache and configuring the sites-available here is the result:
Sites-available
(It is not seen in the image, but I have closed the < /VitualHost>)
, also i create a symlink to the downloaded files in your apache www directory so that whenever someone navigates to the "website" they are automatically taken to the mirror files here is the command: "sudo ln -s /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ /var/www/ubuntu". and i change the file permissions here is the comand: *"sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/ubuntu".
To sum up, in the client i changed the url from the file: sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.lists here is the result:sources.list client.  i only modified the archive.ubuntu.com and the security.ubuntu.com, to my ip static of the ubuntu server and change the name of the version to jammy. finally when i do the apt update sends to me this error:
apt update results
And also i tried with wget and sent this to me:
wget
Other thinks that I don't comment:
There aren't a firewall blocking
The files of /var/spool/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ also have permission
When I go to the website and i put the ip static of the server i found 2 folders that is: pool/ and dists/.
